# Scoring using H2O Flow, on another day

Tags: h2o

If the goal is to use H2O Flow interface for scoring (which is great BTW), how to accomplish this after a reboot or a system crash?

Is there a way to save models and rerun it, **within H2O Flow**, without having to train sets again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:
- export the model using the UI

on another day/running a clean instance:
- import the model using the UI
- import and parse the files used
- run predict, select the imported model

Important: h2o version used on exporting and importing should be the same